# Minecraft keeps crashing (Vanilla)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My minecraft keeps crashing whenever i log into a online server, i have no idea why but i do indeed have the crash report.

```
[20:36:48] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: APoisonPotato93
[20:36:48] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:f32c25b375584675aa0b0b1eaed7fe4b:29ed969693cd41bda6666aa49813b952)
[20:36:53] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[20:36:54] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[20:36:54] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[20:36:54] [Thread-6/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[20:36:54] [Thread-6/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[20:36:55] [Thread-6/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[20:36:55] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[20:37:01] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x512 textures-atlas
[20:37:09] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to mc.sparkade.net, 25565
[20:37:13] [Client thread/FATAL]: Error executing task
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(1) + length(83) exceeds writerIndex(6): UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 1, widx: 6, cap: 6)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at g.a(SourceFile:61) [1.8.4.jar:?]
    at ave.av(SourceFile:880) [1.8.4.jar:?]
    at ave.a(SourceFile:325) [1.8.4.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124) [1.8.4.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(1) + length(83) exceeds writerIndex(6): UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 1, widx: 6, cap: 6)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1175) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:655) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at em.readBytes(SourceFile:669) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    at em.c(SourceFile:243) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    at bcy.a(SourceFile:1291) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    at gg.a(SourceFile:52) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    at gg.a(SourceFile:9) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    at fh$1.run(SourceFile:13) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at g.a(SourceFile:60) ~[1.8.4.jar:?]
    ... 3 more
[20:37:13] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] You have no new mail.
```

Now, if anyone could help me fix this, it would be much appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: Is your mine craft up to date? And does this happen with all servers?

Comment: Ya it happens with all of them, and yes it is updated to the latest version. I was playing on it then it just stopped worked, crashed and now it wont work. im going to try it on single player right now.

Comment: How about your java? Check that is up to date.

Comment: How do i do that? I'm not familiar with Java. =/

Comment: Link: https://java.com/en/download/ Just download it and launch it to update

Comment: Its still not working. =P

Comment: In the error it says to visit http://www.lwjgl.org about "The binding of open AL" I'll see what I can find

Comment: Try getting the download from the link above, perhaps this will fix it.

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat lwjgl is just another library that Minecraft uses and downloads automatically. There is no need to download it manually, and even if you do, where would you place the files?

Comment: Have you reinstalled Minecraft? As in deleted the `versions`, `assets` and `libraries` folders from `%appdata%\.minecraft`? (You can also just delete a specific subfolder of `version`, in case you have modded versions you'd like to keep.) Afterwards, just start the game and try again.

Comment: Is there any problems if you go on a singleplayer world?

Comment: Ya it does not work on single payer either. Im going to try re-installing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You should try reinstalling your Minecraft

Make sure you copy out the `saves` folder first, then remove the entire`.minecraft` folder.

Comment: i will do that!

Comment: @jacobtohahn I can't help but notice, but you should clean up (edit) some of your previous posts as they're poorly written. Also, avoid posting multiple answers. Instead, edit your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, it crashes when writing to a file(probably auto-saves). You either have an corrupted save directory or it's read-only or inaccessible or something like that.

Answer (score -2):

I have just uninstalled Minecraft then re-installed it. It does indeed work now. I don't know why I didn't do this before i came on here and asked for help. Regardless, thank you for your help guys. :)

Comment: If the suggestion to reinstall is what helped you, you should vote up and acccept that answer.